# How to show loading progressdialog spinning wheel in an Android homescreen widget

Tags: android, widget, loading, progressdialog

I've seen some Android widgets show the spinning wheel loading animation (same animation as an indeterminate ProgressDialog) when fetching information from the web. How do you do this for homescreen widgets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9407916/1012284

Comment: @PadmaKumar That is not for widgets...

Comment: Found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442183/using-the-animated-circle-in-an-imageview-while-loading-stuff

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but possibly an [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) could work.