# How to make a loading screen while doing a huge process

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar, loading, android-loader

i want to make a loading screen while the android app is doing a huge process like finding prime numbers in a range.it takes a long time for the process to done and i want to appear a loading screen or progress bar while it is doing the huge process. here are the codes of my app:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show "Loading" status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407858/how-to-show-loading-status-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple ProgressDialog.

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Loading..");
progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
progress.setCancelable(true);
```

when you need to start it, call

```
progress.show();
```

when you need to dismiss it, call

```
progress.dismiss();
```